# The problem of determining whether a given context-free grammar generates the empty string

Tags: context-free-grammar, turing-machines

I was unsure if you were to formulate this problem as a language would it be correct to say  is ECFG = {  | G is a CFG with L(G) = ∅ }? Otherwise im unsure how you would write it as a language.